# Jsoup - retrieving & manipulating data

Tags: java, android, jsoup

So I'm having trouble figuring out how to manipulate the data completely that I'm scraping using Jsoup. I know how to target the areas but i don't know how to target them individually but still group them together.

For Example:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <p> Heading1 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p> Body1 <p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <p> Heading2 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p> Body2 <p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <p> Heading3 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p> Body3 <p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <p> Heading4 </p>
    </div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <p> Body4 <p>
</div>
```

I want to target different sections in this HTML and then place them in textViews a certain way. But when I try to for example target div.panel-heading & div.panel-body and I want to place the heading above the body it will repeat all of the div.panel-headings for the entire page first then below that it will repeat all of the div.panel-bodys. It's printing them in totally separate groups instead of one on top of the other.

Below is the code I'm using:

```
private void arbitrage() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            final StringBuilder builder2 = new StringBuilder();

            try {

                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("THE URL HERE").get();
                Elements links = doc.select("div.panel.panel-default > div.panel-heading");
                Elements links2 = doc.select("div.panel.panel-default > div.panel-body");

                for (Element link : links) {
                    builder.append("\n").append(link.text());

                    builder2.append("\n").append(links2.text() + "\n");

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                builder.append("Error : ").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
            }


            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    arbitrage.setText(builder.toString() + builder2.toString());
                }
            });



        }
    }).start();

}
```

==-=-=-=-=-=-  EDITED =-=-=-=-=--

I've changed the HTML code to better reflect what the web URL looks like. When I run my current code it displays.

```
Heading1
Heading2
Heading3
Heading4

Body1
Body2
Body3
Body4
```

I want it to display as follows.

```
Heading1
Body1

Heading2
Body2

Heading3
Body3

Heading4
Body4
```

So essentially, I want to grab the panel-heading & panel-body individually, but display them together in a group. I can grab them both in one group by selecting div.panel.panel-default, but I don't have as much control on how this is displayed from a UI standpoint. At least I don't know how to manipulate that data when I scrape it all together like that.

EDIT TWO =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

I'm getting close, this code allows me to manipulate the data individually better, but still cant do what I need. I want to style the heading & body let's say different colors. I can't figure this out.

```
 for (Element panel : panels) {
                        Elements links = panel.select("div.panel-heading");
                        Elements links2 = panel.select("div.panel-body");
                        builder.append("\n").append(links.text()).append("\n").append("\n").append(links2.text())
                                .append("\n")
                                .append("\n");

                    }
```

changed my runOnUIThread to this:

```
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        arbitrageTextView.setText(builder.toString());
                    }
                });
```

But if I want to like change the text color for the header different from the body I'm not able to. Or add a divider between all of the groups, doesn't allow me to do this. It just seems very limited on the UI side of things, doesn't allow me to stylize them, just pull them in and display them. I believe this is because it's pulling it all in under one textView, would I need to put them in two different textViews?

Comment: I cannot understand your question completely. I have run the code and its doing what it's suppose to do. Can you give an example of what you want?

Comment: @RizwanEjaz I've updated my question and the  HTML to better reflect what the URL looks like. I've also added what my current code outputs and what I want it to output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Elements panels = doc.select("div.panel.panel-default");

for (Element panel : panels) {
    Elements links = panel.select("div.panel-heading");
    Elements links2 = panel.select("div.panel-body");
    builder.append("\n").append(links.text());
    builder.append("\n").append(links2.text() + "\n");
}
```

**Update**
I changed code

Comment: This seems to print out the same way as my current code. Still prints all of the panel-headings on the page first then will print all the panel-body second. I've updated my question to more clearly represent what I'm trying to do along with what my current code prints out and what I want it to print out. Thanks!

Comment: Wait I think I was able to modify your code some to get it to work.

Comment: I changed code very little. Just add elements text to one StringBuilder

Comment: I've added another update to show what I have now. I believe I did what you just mentioned, changed them into one Stringbuilder. But if I wanted to style them differently, let's say heading blue and body red. How would I go about this? Am I approaching it completely wrong?